# Issue with receiving gzip request via apex REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api

I'm implementing the integration between Salesforce and SMS services (Twilio and Clicksend). To receive messages I am using the Public RESTful Web Service as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html). Here is the code example:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/messageService')
global class ReceiveMessages
{
    static Map<String, String> urlParamentersMap;

    @HttpPost
    global static void postMessage()
    {
        if( !AppSetting.appEnabled) return;
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        urlParamentersMap = (Map<String,String>)req.params;
        RestContext.response.headers.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        processMessage();
    }
}
```

It works okay for both services if I use English in my messages. However, if my messages contain UTF-8 characters (eg. Cyrillic or Chinese) I am receiving a corrupted text from Clicksend.

I send - [image: test]

I receive from Twilio - [image: test]

I receive from Clicksend - [image: test corrupted]

The encoding in the request body looks identical:

Request from Twilio - `Body=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82`

Request from Clicksend - `body=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82`

I did some investigations of the requests and the only difference seems to be in the accept-encoding header.

Request from Twilio:

```
Headers
x-forwarded-for 54.211.233.91
connection  close
user-agent  TwilioProxy/1.1
cache-control   max-age=259200
host    webhook.site
content-length  422
accept  * / *
x-twilio-signature  748Shd6xVwky9EhwNi0FAUmDXCY=
content-type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request from Clicksend:

```
Headers
connection  close
x-forwarded-for 52.64.176.55
host    webhook.site
content-length  475
content-type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
accept-encoding gzip, deflate
user-agent  ClickSend.com
accept  application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
```

Twilio has no such header in its request and Clicksend has `accept-encoding : gzip, deflate`. According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_compression.htm) looks like Salesforce should compose/decompose such requests but there are a lot of concerns in the community.

I assume that the gzip compression could cause this issue but I'm not sure at all. Maybe someone faced similar issues with Clicksend or with Salesforce endpoints.

Can you please advise or point where I did something wrong?